# C++ template class with non-type parameter: how to overload the assign operator?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm writing a template class with non-type parameter

```
class Test
{   
public:
    Test() { std::cout << "Test::Test()" << std::endl; }

    Test(Test const&) { std::cout << "Test::Test(Test const&)" << std::endl; }

     ~Test() { std::cout << "Test::~Test()" << std::endl; }

     Test& operator=(Test const&)
     {
           std::cout << "Test& Test::operator=(Test const&)" << std::endl;
           return *this;
     }

     void print() const { std::cout << "Test::print() const" << std::endl; }
     void print() { std::cout << "Test::print()" << std::endl; }
};
```

Above is my "test" class to test my template class and

```
template <typename T, unsigned int n>
class Array
{
private:
    T* value;
public:
    Array() {
        this->value = new T[n];
    }

    ~Array() {
        delete[] this->value;
    }

    Array* operator=(const Array* arr)
    {
        this->value = arr->value;
        return this->value;
    }

    T& operator[](int a) {
        return this->value[a];
    }

    unsigned int size()
    {
        return n;
    }
};
```

Above is my template class with non-type parameter.

```
int main(int, char*[])
{
 /*first*/   Array<Test, 3> arr_1;

 /*second*/  Array<Test, 3> arr_3 = arr_1;

 return 0;
}
```

In my main.cpp file,

I make class test object 3 times with the first one,

and I want to overload the assign operator to do the second one.

I tried with

```
Array* operator=(const Array* arr)
{
    this->value = arr->value;
    return this->value;
}
```

but it 'segfaults' after calling the destructor infinitely.

I'd like to know how can I write the assign operator overload in this case.

Thank you!

Comment: Typically, an assignment operator would take in a *reference* to an object of the same type, not a *pointer*. Was that intentional?

Comment: `Array<Test, 3> arr_3 = arr_1;` uses a copy constructor, not a copy assignment operator. In any case, `Array` doesn't explicitly implement either; both are implicitly defined.

Comment: @templatetypedef, I tried with Array& operator=(const Array& arr) but it didn't change the result. Maybe I'm not properly implenting the method.

Comment: Your code works by doing a shallow pointer assignment rather than a deep copy, which I think might be contributing to the issue.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik, so basically Array<Test, 3> arr_3 = arr_1; is Array(const Array& arr)?

Comment: If `Array` class provides `Array(const Array& arr)` constructor, `Array<Test, 3> arr_3 = arr_1;` will call it, if that's what you are asking.

Comment: @templatetypedef, Thank you for your comment! I'll try with deep copy. But the implementation of the method seems okay to you?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, thank you for your comment! I'll try to implement it!

Comment: @templatetypedef I solved the issue with   Array& operator=(const Array& arr)
    {
        this->value = new T[n];
        int a = n;
        int b = 0;
        while(a != 0)
        {
            this->value[b] = arr.value[b];
            b++;
            a--;
        }
        return *this;
    }

Comment: What you did is copy the pointer to the allocated `int[]`, and the reason this becomes a problem is because when an `Array` object goes out of scope, it deletes the allocated `int[]`. This means that when one `Array` object goes out of scope, all the other ones which have copied from it get a dangling pointer (since it was deleted!). Then when the second array (which copied the pointer from the first) goes out of scope it tries to free the already freed pointer, which makes for undefined behaviour and can therefore result in a crash.

Comment: @McMuffinton, Thank you so much for your answer, I just read it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implement copy, you need something like this:

```
// Copy constructor. When you write Array b = a, the compiler actually calls this, not operator=
Array( const Array& src )
{
    this->value = new T[ n ];
    std::copy_n( src.value, n, value );
}
Array& operator=( const Array& src )
{
    // No need for new[], operator= is called after the object is already constructed.
    std::copy_n( src.value, n, value );
    return *this;
}
```

However, you shouldn't reinvent wheels. There're decent template classes already in the C++ standard library. If your arrays are small (e.g. 3), use `std::array<Test, 3>`. If your arrays are large and you want to keep them off the stack, you can use either `std::unique_ptr<std::array<Test, 3>>`, or `std::vector<Test>`

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!